# How to get an instance variable from rails using angularjs and ui router?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, variables, instance, angular-ui-router

I'm using a template in my state router.  I want to get an instance variable from my rails server, but it doesn't have it's own path, so I can't use Restangular or something like that.  Also, when I try to interpolate:

```
#{@variable}
```

nothing happens, because I'm in a template in my ui router, and not in a rails view.

So how do I get an instance variable from my rails server into angularjs in a ui-router template?

EDIT:

ahaa.... just pass it in like this:

```
 ng-init="variablename = 'variable'"
```

so in my case:

```
ng-init="varname = '#{@variable}' "
```

what's important to notice is two things: 
1. the '' within the ""
2. pass this in on your RAILS VIEW, BEFORE you hand it off to the ui router with ui-view=""

then in the ui template, you can just say {{varname}}  and it should be there :)