# Angular and Ruby on Rails. Is it worth importing instance variables into Angular (and if so, how)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm working on a web app with the client side made in Angular and the backend made in Ruby on Rails. The app will need to show a list of articles (dynamically generated data).

Here’s what I’m pondering about.

Online tutorials on building Angular apps coupled with Ruby on Rails are based on the following model of interactions between the client and the server. First, the client sends a request to the server, in response to which the server will send all the building blocks required to start up Angular, and then Angular will request all the missing data from the server. In my case, first Angular starts up then it requests a list of articles.

That's two request-response cycles, as illustrated by the following diagram.

[image]

What if, on the other hand, the server will during the very first response send the data necessary to display the initial view? Like, in my case, what if the first response also contained the first batch of articles to be somehow imported into Angular? Then there will be only one request-response cycle as shown on the following schematic:

[image]

Is this a good idea or a terrible one? And if it is not absolutely terrible, what is the way to import Rails’ instance variables (e.g. the first batch of articles sent as `@articles`) into Angular while it starts up?

*(I found similar questions discussed — though very briefly and without any consensus reached — [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254649/using-ng-init-to-initialize-data-in-angular-controller) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943083/how-to-get-an-instance-variable-from-rails-using-angularjs-and-ui-router).)*

=======================

**UPDATE:**

OK, here is another StackOverflow discussion about this:

[How to bootstrap data as it it were fetched by a $resource service in Angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451864/how-to-bootstrap-data-as-it-it-were-fetched-by-a-resource-service-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good idea or a terrible one?

I'd argue it's a *Good Idea*. It will improve your app's performance and requires minimally invasive changes. You could even configure your Angular app to conditionally make the requests in case the data isn't available on page load for some reason.

The [Gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem makes it trivial to use your controller instance vars in your views (as JS).

Comment: Sorry that I haven't responded for a long time. I was hoping someone else might get interested in this question and will join the discussion, but no such luck. Thank you for introducing Gon to me — by following the link and then googling around I also found another technique for passing initial variables to Angular. Apparently it's just as simple as declaring a global variable (`<script>var data = @data</script>`) and then accessing this global variable from inside Angular.